# Modify google spreadsheet using its public URL and .net library without auth

Tags: c#, .net, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I have a google spreadsheet URL that was shared with me with "everyone that have link is able to edit" rights
I need to be able to put smth in it's cells but I have no idea how to do it and google docs don't help with this.
Any ideas? 
Google doc share url is https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oKSViNtjtaKjdckJBiIQEZHgbUImnmiNOCQsYpIGdl0/edit?usp=sharing

I can do anything with it via web browser, so I probably can do it with .net library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

1. Create a new google project at https://console.developers.google.com and create a service account key.
2. Add "Drive api"
3. Write some code

   ```
   static void DoSheet()
   {
       var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"cert.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
       const string scope = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds https://docs.google.com/feeds";
       var credential = new
       ServiceAccountCredential(
           new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer("project email")
           {
               Scopes = new[] { scope }
           }.FromCertificate(certificate));

       var requestFactory = new GDataRequestFactory("App name");
       bool success = credential.RequestAccessTokenAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken.None).Result;
       requestFactory.CustomHeaders.Add($"Authorization: Bearer {credential.Token.AccessToken}");

       var service = new SpreadsheetsService("myproject-id") {RequestFactory = requestFactory};
       var path = $"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/1oKSViNtjtaKjdckJBiIQEZHgbUImnmiNOCQsYpIGdl0/private/full";
       var query = new WorksheetQuery(path);
       var feed = service.Query(query);
       var worksheet = (WorksheetEntry)feed.Entries[0];
       var cellQuery = new CellQuery(worksheet.CellFeedLink);
       var cellFeed = service.Query(cellQuery);
       // Iterate through each cell, printing its value.
       foreach (var atomEntry in cellFeed.Entries)
       {
           var cell = (CellEntry) atomEntry;
           if (cell.Title.Text == "A1")
           {
               cell.InputValue = "200";
               cell.Update();
           }
           else if (cell.Title.Text == "B1")
           {
               cell.InputValue = "=SUM(A1, 200)";
               cell.Update();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

The trick here is to get Sheet Id and use it in the query url with /private/full after that